# Folder Picker Dialog

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint

I am currently using `FolderBrowserDialog` to select a folder in my .NET solution.  However, this dialog does not allow me to select SharePoint folders, just local or network folders.

I would like to use something similar to `SaveFileDialog` or `OpenFileDialog`, because they allow browsing SharePoint folders.  However, these options seem to require that you specify or select a specific file, rather than a folder.

Is there a way to use create a ***folder*** picker similar to `SaveFileDialog` or `OpenFileDialog`?  Ideas in VB.NET or C# are welcome.

UPDATE:

As a workaround, I am now using the folder picker from an Office application, like this:

```
app.FileDialog(Office.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

where `app` can be the Excel, PowerPoint, Word, etc. application object.  I would still prefer not to have to reference an Office app to pull this off, but it's the only option I have found so far.  I did not submit this as the answer because I am hoping for a real solution, rather than a workaround.

Comment: I would say to `inherit` the `FolderBrowserDialog` ***but you can not***. It sound like you would need to create a custom control to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog works for you you can select a file and then use the command
C#

> Path.GetDirectoryName(path_to_file);
>   or in VB.net
>   Path.GetDirectoryName(path_to_file)

I don't know if it fill your needs... It depends where you need this code and if the folder starts empty or not, as you know if the folder starts empty this method will not work

This if you decide to stop using

> Office.MsoFileDialogType